# Cannot find pdfLatex after upgrade to Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)

Tags: macos, pdflatex

I just upgraded to Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) now `pdflatex` cannot be found.

I am using TexWorks to compile.

I get the error TeX may be installed I just need to find it.

Where can I find the install location? I checked the settings and TexWorks reports LaTeX was in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`. How can I fix this issue?

TexWorks recommends me check `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Why the down vote? How can I improve the question?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Mine was moved to `/Library/TeX/Root/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex`, hope that helps!

Comment: $ ls /Library/TeX/Root/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex
ls: /Library/TeX/Root/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex: No such file or directory

Answer (score 8):

If you are using *homebrew*, you'll get this message on the client:

> Installing TeX from source is weird and gross, requires a lot of
>   patches, and only builds 32-bit (and thus can't use Homebrew deps on
>   Snow Leopard.)
>
> We recommend using a MacTeX distribution: https://www.tug.org/mactex/
>
> You can install it using Cask:
>
> brew cask install mactex

So that's exactly what I'm doing.  Using *'sudo'* in front of the command, though, to facilitate installation.

After this, on pre-El Capitan systems, pdflatex would be found in **/usr/texbin**, however, with El Capitan, installations to /usr are no longer allowed.  Hence, you will now find pdflatex and other related binaries in **/Library/TeX/texbin**.  (Many thanks to the R-Bloggers website for this suggestion.)  Just add this path to your $PATH env variable.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Mine moved to /Library/TeX/Root/bin/x86_64-darwin as well. I added this path in my TeXworks Preferences->Typesetting tab under the "Paths for TeX and related programs". Everything seems to be working as usual, though I have not yet checked raw tex and ConTeXt. But I guess things should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

I use zsh and had to add `/Library/TeX/texbin` to my path in `~/.zshrc` with:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Library/TeX/texbin"
```

since zsh doesn't, apparently, use `/usr/libexec/path_helper` to load `/etc/paths.d` automatically and I didn't want to throw another variable into the equation by adding it (and all the other stuff in `/etc/paths.d`) without spending more time figuring out exactly what else that was going to do.

Answer (score 2):

Just to mention that if you want to add the path in TexShop. The correct tab is "Engine"--"Path settings", and paste "/Library/TeX/Root/bin/x86_64-darwin" to the first input line.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

TeXworks -> Preferences -> Typesetting

Click the + button for the first box and Choose the path of texbin which  contain many file including pdflatex.

In my case this the path:
/Library/TeX/Distributions/Programs/texbin

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i typed a command "which pdflatex" at the terminal then it shows /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex. After that, i selected the option in the preferences as in this picture:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  This looks like a slightly different route to Raju Ranjan Kumar's answer.  When you have a little more rep, it would probably be more appropriate to post minor variations to another answer as a comment, as it's intended that each answer provide a substantially different solution than what's already been contributed.